# Can you recover a password stored in Apple Remote Desktop?

Tags: password, apple-remote-desktop

I have two servers that haven't been touched in ages. Their passwords have been forgotten and I have a Mac where Apple Remote Desktop has saved their passwords. Can I view those saved passwords? I'd prefer not to reset both these servers and start from scratch.

What I've checked so far:

**Keychain Access** - This appears to only store the ARD password. I presume this password encrypts the connection details separately (and I recall the password here being the one I used to setup ARD in the first place).

The documentation (for V2 anyway) suggests data is stored in three places, user library plist, /Library plist, and /var/db/RemoteManagement/: images.apple.com/remotedesktop/pdf/ARD_Admin_Guide.pdf

The data in **/var/** seems to be an sqlite3 database with usage statistics

The **/Library/** plist seems to be nothing eye catching.

**~/Library/** plist (in containers nowadays) has all the machine details but <s>I don't see anything resembling a password (encrypted or not)</s>. Oh, they're stored with the key name "accessCredentials". Time to learn how to decrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve finally found something that does what I need.

https://github.com/ygini/ARD-Inspector

ARD Inspector can open and view the details in the com.Apple.AppleRemoteDesktop.plist including the encrypted  password(s). You must have the ARD “master password” in order to decrypt the information.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Apple Remote Password doesnt store passwords, that they are instead stored in keychain on the target Mac. Search for 'remote' in keychain access, see if it is there

Comment: That was the first thing I tried with no luck. The only entry is the ARD password. I presume it uses this password to encrypt the client credentials separately. The documentation (for V2 anyway) suggests data is stored in three places, user library plist, /Library plist, and /var/db/RemoteManagement/: https://images.apple.com/remotedesktop/pdf/ARD_Admin_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I found my passwords by searching for "Microsoft" in the "Keychain Access" app. They were listed under `com.microsoft.rdc.macos`.

Comment: This is a different app. The app you're talking about is Microsoft Remote Desktop or Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection. The original post was about Apple Remote Desktop.